# StageWebView: Missing images on some websites

Tags: actionscript-3, air, stagewebview

in my AIR Desktop-Application I use the StageWebView to display several Websites. For some websites everything works fine - for example when I try to load flickr.com. I can see the site with all informations and images.

But on other sites all images are missing (for example on http://www.mazda.de). I see the basic structure and all texts, but no images.

I really have no idea what to do - probably some settings for the flash player?
I would appreciate any help.

Thank you and kind regards!

Comment: are you on a home network or company network? Some company can block downloading of images from unregistered websites.

Comment: I tried it from two different home networks - both with the same result: No images.